# Question about information loss and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, information-theory, entropy, projection

I'm trying to clarify somethings about information theory and dimension reduction.
Now consider a random vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we use a set of unit vector $a_i$'s $\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $i \in \{1,2,\ldots d\}$ $(d<n)$ to project $x$, i.e. $s = x^T[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d]$
Our target is to preserve information as much as possible, if angle of $a_1$ and $a_2$ is close to 0 or 180 degree (or $a_1^Ta_2 $ is close to 1 or -1), $x^Ta_2$ may contain most of information $x^Ta_1$, so we can imagine intuitively we need $a_i$'s to be pairwise-orthogonal.
 If $a_1^Ta_2=0$, we would not have any redundant information of $x^Ta_1$ in the representation of $x^Ta_2$ 
Is there any mathematical theorem based on some materials in information theory like entropy, mutual information to support that if we want to preserve most information, the basis we select should be orthogonal?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The observation is nice but what is the mathematical meaning of most information? Or redundancy here?

Comment: @Sam Sorry for late reply, I didn't notice my mail box. In my opinion, no redundancy means if I know $x^Ta_1$, I can't get any information of other $x^Ta_i$, so the mutual information of $x^Ta_i$ and $x^Ta_j$ should be 0 if i is not equal to j. Maybe from this point we can show something

Comment: I have no idea how to formulate pdf of any entry after projection if I have the original pdf. If we start from mutual information, I think it is necessary to find out pdf.

Comment: What is the definition of mutual information? That could be used to show something I guess.

Comment: You can see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) for its definition. It starts from pdf of target random variable, so I think the pdf of projected entry would be necessary.